# Debugging in chrome with webpack-dev-server: Uncaught reference error, {variable} undefined

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am beginning with Webpack and the webpack-dev-server plugin, and I am facing some confusion. After launching the webpack-dev-server using an npm script with the --watch and --open flags, I noticed I can not access any of the variables, declared in the global scope of my script, using the chrome devtools console.

**Excerpt of npm scripts from package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --env.mode development",
    "live": "webpack-dev-server --env.mode development --watch --open",
    "prod": "webpack --env.mode production"
  },
```

**Example code from 'index.js'**

```
const foo = 'bar';
console.log(foo);
```

**Console output**

```
bar
>foo
VM1361:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM1361:1
```

On the initial page load, the console logs the value of foo, which is 'bar'.
But if I try to access foo in the console I receive the error as shown above.

On the initial page load, the 'bar' output from the console.log(foo) statement is referring to index.js:2 [[webpack:///./src/js/index.js]]

Why is it that while trying (produces error) to access the foo variable from the console, does it refer to the location VM1361:1 [[debugger:///VM1361:1]]

I would really appreciate any help on how to resolve this, since I suppose I am clearly missing something here.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the bundle file generated by webpack? You seem to declare a global var, but in reality,the variable's in IIFE. It isn't global, it's scoped.

```js
// In your bundle.js, search for a, you'll find the snippet below.
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

var a = 1;
console.log(a);

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export your variable as a property of the global window object:

```
var window.foo = 'bar';
console.log(window.foo)
```